# Load external js file to execute javascript code in IE devtool bar console

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I want to use jquery to automatically fill some details in a web site which is not having reference to jquery. Using IE devtool bar script console, I want to load jquery then use it to write some code. But I do not know how to load jquery file and then use it.
Can anybody help me in that?

Comment: inserting `<script src="jquery..."> </script>` to the DOM would do, Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy this in your adresse bar or console:

```
javascript:var s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('src', 'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);void(s);
```

Comment: Strange. It works, try on this page if you want :-). Be careful, sometimes, when you paste it, the brower removes "javascript:" at the beginning, and you have to add it again before submitting the link.

Comment: Can you tell me how you will use jQuery code after putting the code you mentioned?

Comment: I copy past this in my browser debug console, then I type jQuery.fn.jquery, and I get the current version of the jquery I've just loaded.